# Sorting through large ugly file

Tags: excel

I have an excel document that is, and looks physically like a report.  I only need some of the data.  What is the best of coming up with a formula that gets me this information.  Document has 88 entries.

You can click the image for a full-size version:

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

I want to come up with a search that returns the stuff in yellow.  Any idea how to get that done?  Or is this a manual search type of deal?  I'm asking, not because I want to save 3 hours on doing this, but because I would like to save time in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: We need more information about how your sheet is setup. For instance, do you always want the cells `B7,B9,B10,J4,J6,H34` to be extracted or do you want to find specific information in the sheet wherever it is and extract it? Are the entries on separate worksheets or all on the same worksheet?

Comment: ...and building on Engineer Toast's comments - What do you want to do with the data once it's found? Write it down? Copy it somewhere?

Comment: @EngineerToast all of the entries are on the same worksheet.  Would like it to extract cells, but I need it to determine what those cells are, since the exact cell number changes +1 or -1 in each report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your template is in the same format, the below code should work. I tried to keep it as simple as possible so you can see what the individual steps do. You an adjust the columns where the data is pasted to suit. You will need to first create a sheet called 'Extract' and change any occurrence of 'YourSheetNameHere' within the code.

```
Sub Extract()
Dim Page, Company, Num, Name, ProjMan, TotalVal, Fee As String
Dim r, c As Integer

    c = 1
    Sheets("YourSheetNameHere").Select


    For r = 1 To 4680
        If Left(Range("J" & r).Value, 4) = "Page" Then

        'Stores the values
            Page = Range("J" & r)
            ProjMan = Range("J" & r + 2)
            TotalVal = Range("J" & r + 4)
            Company = Range("J" & r + 4)
            Num = Range("J" & r + 6)
            Name = Range("J" & r + 7)
            Fee = Range("H" & r + 31)

        'Pastes the values in a new sheet called Extract (which you will need to create first)
            Sheets("Extract").Select
            Range("A" & c) = Page
            Range("B" & c) = ProjMan
            Range("C" & c) = TotalVal
            Range("D" & c) = Company
            Range("E" & c) = Num
            Range("F" & c) = Name
            Range("G" & c) = Fee

            c = c + 1

            Sheets("YourSheetNameHere").Select 'You will need to adjust to suit
        End If
    Next r


End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help!  I have no experience with VBA, but this will be a learning experience.  This sheet repeats around every 50 new or so rows, but the number varies.  Will I need to tell excel there is a new data set between like 37 and 50, or is there someway I can tell it that every time it sees Report Date, in column B, that we are seeing a new report page?  I would like the data to be written down in a row entry for every report.

Comment: Also, cells are not printed yellow, I made them yellow for vizulization

Comment: To use VBA you will need to save your file as a .xlsm. Then show the Developer tab (by going to File > Options > Customize Ribbon and checking the Developer checkbox) This brings up a new tab where you can click on the Visual Basic Icon, create a module and then paste the code in there. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do this online.

Comment: Also, I am unsure what you mean by 'This sheet repeats every 50 new rows'. Do you mean that sometimes there are multiple templates like the one in the picture on the same sheet? If so, what is the maximum row number that there is data in and the maximum column number for any given sheet?

Comment: And finally, if it is not the cell color you are matching on, how do you know what data you are trying to pull? Is it always Company, NUMBER, NAME, PROJECT MGR, EST TOTAL VAL, and the Fee Computed from the 'Incurred' column? Once you have this data, what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Thanks again so much for your help! 'This sheet repeats every 50 new rows' - Around every 50 or so rows, this template (pictured above) is repeated, and pasted again in the same document.  That number of rows does changes, based off what is in it.  Max row = 4680.  Max column = J.

Comment: Yes, it's always these values "Company, NUMBER, NAME, PROJECT MGR, EST TOTAL VAL, and the Fee Computed from the 'Incurred'".  Once I have this data, I would like it to make a new sheet, that enters a new row for each template, enters the Company, NUMBER, NAME, PROJECT MGR, EST TOTAL VAL, and the Fee Computed from the 'Incurred' across columns, and then searches the next template.